# Having a hard time trying to isolate part of array :(

Tags: javascript

Here is the array

```
[ 'michael@ecorp.com:qnyynf',
  'esteban@ecorp.com:uneyrl',
  'marquis@ecorp.com:gnlybe',
  'denver@ecorp.com:eboreg',
  'robin@ecorp.com:zbaxrl',
  'royce@ecorp.com:gubznf',
  'van@ecorp.com:fgnejnef',
  'tony@ecorp.com:cnff',
  'thomas@ecorp.com:zvpunry',
  'dave@ecorp.com:gvttre',
  'benjamin@ecorp.com:fhcrezna',
  'napoleon@ecorp.com:guhaqre',
  'luke@ecorp.com:enatre',
  'santos@ecorp.com:zvpuryyr',
  'orlando@ecorp.com:npprff',
  'wilbur@ecorp.com:cevaprff',
  'stan@ecorp.com:cnffjbeq',
  'kurtis@ecorp.com:fhafuvar',
  'dee@ecorp.com:fhzzre',
  'timothy@ecorp.com:wrffvpn' ]
```

Im trying to move only the passwords for each email tried with indexing ':' but indexing commas breaks it.
still a noob trying to understand these types of arrays

How would you achieve this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to be more clear on your goal and show your attempt better

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Could you show some code that you've tried? Also are you trying to move the passwords into a separate array?

Comment: Not sure what is expected output, but if i understand you correctly, you need: final = arr.map(el => el.split(':')[1]);   or [0] if you want just emails....

Comment: Honestly i have tried converting to string using concat substring last indexes and so on.

Comment: Please show your expected result, or comment on the answers given.

Comment: There are no expected results its part of a much larger problem
Next step is throwing the passwords into                                                                  

var password = toolkit.rot13('oernx-n-yrt');
console.log(password);                                                               but it throws this error /home/workshop9/node_modules/crypto-toolkit/src/crypto/internals/caesar-cypher.js:22
    .split("")
     ^

TypeError: pass.split is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
//define array (as you have)
const array = ["1a:1b", "2a:2b", "3a:3b", "4a:4b"];

//map each item within that array. 'item' in this context is any array item. So essentially below is similar to a 'for each' command.
const passwords_001 = array.map(item => {
    //I'm splitting each string, using the colon as the marker for 'seperator' 
    //i.e anything before or after it will be it's own item in the 'itemAsArray' array
    var itemAsArray = item.split(':');

    //pop() is taking the last item of the relevant array and removing it, but also returning it. 
    //This can then be passed as an item for the array we are mapping i.e passwords_001
    var password = itemAsArray.pop();

    //return the password as the new array item
    return password;
});

//log the passwords_001 array to see only the passwords returned
console.log(passwords_001);

//console output
//["1b", "2b", "3b", "4b"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```js
console.log([ 'michael@ecorp.com:qnyynf', 'esteban@ecorp.com:uneyrl', 'marquis@ecorp.com:gnlybe', 'denver@ecorp.com:eboreg', 'robin@ecorp.com:zbaxrl', 'royce@ecorp.com:gubznf', 'van@ecorp.com:fgnejnef', 'tony@ecorp.com:cnff', 'thomas@ecorp.com:zvpunry', 'dave@ecorp.com:gvttre', 'benjamin@ecorp.com:fhcrezna', 'napoleon@ecorp.com:guhaqre', 'luke@ecorp.com:enatre', 'santos@ecorp.com:zvpuryyr', 'orlando@ecorp.com:npprff', 'wilbur@ecorp.com:cevaprff', 'stan@ecorp.com:cnffjbeq', 'kurtis@ecorp.com:fhafuvar', 'dee@ecorp.com:fhzzre', 'timothy@ecorp.com:wrffvpn' ]
.map(e => e.split(':')[1]));
```

Or this?

```js
console.log([ 'michael@ecorp.com:qnyynf', 'esteban@ecorp.com:uneyrl', 'marquis@ecorp.com:gnlybe', 'denver@ecorp.com:eboreg', 'robin@ecorp.com:zbaxrl', 'royce@ecorp.com:gubznf', 'van@ecorp.com:fgnejnef', 'tony@ecorp.com:cnff', 'thomas@ecorp.com:zvpunry', 'dave@ecorp.com:gvttre', 'benjamin@ecorp.com:fhcrezna', 'napoleon@ecorp.com:guhaqre', 'luke@ecorp.com:enatre', 'santos@ecorp.com:zvpuryyr', 'orlando@ecorp.com:npprff', 'wilbur@ecorp.com:cevaprff', 'stan@ecorp.com:cnffjbeq', 'kurtis@ecorp.com:fhafuvar', 'dee@ecorp.com:fhzzre', 'timothy@ecorp.com:wrffvpn' ]
.map(e => e.split(':')[0]));
```